# How to write the following SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
PROPERTY_FOR_RENT (Pno, Street, Area, City, Pcode, Type, Rooms, Rent, Ono, Sno, Bno)
OWNER (Ono, Fname, Lname, Address, Tel_No)
```

Find the name and address of property owners who have only houses registered with the rental agency.

There are 2 types of PROPERTY(houses,flat ). The "Only" I have no ideal about it

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Address
FROM owner
WHERE Ono
IN (

    SELECT Ono
    FROM property_for_rent
    WHERE TYPE =  "house"
    AND Ono NOT 
    IN (

        SELECT Ono
        FROM property_for_rent
        WHERE TYPE <>  "house"
    )
)
```

This is the way, I tried. Is there any better way?

Comment: Please edit your question and show any attempt you have made to answer this question.

Comment: Should likely be a simple INNER, LEFT join a having, a group by and a count. Take a look at http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ for some help with them.  Think of data in terms of SETS. you need to first get a set of data lists people having something other than houses regiestered, and then a list of owners who have houses registered.  take from the second set, those in the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in several ways.  One way is to use `group by` and `having`.  Another method is to use `not exists`:

```
select o.*
from owner o
where not exists (select 1 from property_for_rent pfr where o.ono = pfr.ono and type <> 'house');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Query

```
Select Fname, Lname, Address from Owner 
Where Ono IN (Select Ono from PROPERTY_FOR_RENT where Type = 'houses' AND Type != 'flat')
```

Comment: This will not work.  Reason: a user could also have a flat THE ONLY as the op pointed out is the problem.  Even with `AND Type != 'flat'` update will not work

Comment: He has only two types houses and flats, and he wants only users who have registered with houses only. please suggest some other query if my query has problems, thanks.

Comment: @Gordon provided a response I don't think can be improved upon.  However, I'll have one using outer joins and having here in a second with an SQL Fiddle example.  I would recommend following the SQL fiddle link I provide and attempt to use the SQL you have above.  You'll see why it doesn't work.  I didn't downvote your, answer simply trying to educate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Gordon's solution to be the most elegant: but since I mentioned it in comments: here's a way to do it in joins and having.

```
Select O.Ono, O.Fname, O.Lname, Count(Distinct P1.Type) cp1 , count(Distinct P2.Type) cp2
FROM Owner O
INNER JOIN Property_for_Rent P1
 on O.Ono = P1.Ono
LEFT JOIN Property_for_Rent P2
 on O.Ono = P1.Ono
 and P1.PNo = P2.PNo
and P2.Type = 'Houses'
Group by Ono,FName,LName
having cp1=Cp2
```

[SQL Fiddle Example:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c0c7b/17/0)

Answer (score -1):

***Step one:*** Join the tables together.
***Hint:*** What column is common to both tables?

Comment: This does not belong as an answer.